# Why properties of project in Harbor can't be modified by a normal user?

Tags: harbor

Non-admin user can not modify properties of his project like "public" through Harbor's Rest API, It returns 405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 1):

That's by design of the access control function. The project settings can be modified by the users with role > `Project Admin`.